# Statistics - expected numbers

Tags: statistics

I really need some help with the remainder of my task.

The number of costumors, arriving at a certain restaurant on one day, follow a Poisson distribution with the parameter μ = 2. The restaurant can serve 3 costumors an hour. If more than 3 costumors arrive on a given hour, the additional costumors (in excess of the 3) are sent away.

I got the first 2 questions answered, but I am having trouble with the expected numbers

---

**Question 3:**
What is the expected number of costumors served on a given hour?

---

I found another very similar question on here were André answered:

---

Let Y be the number of tankers served. The random variable Y takes on the values 0, 1, 2, or 3.

The probabilities Pr(Y=0), Pr(Y=1), and Pr(Y=2) are just the Poisson probabilities. For Pr(Y=3), compute 1−Pr(X≤3). Now that you have Pr(Y=k) for the various values of k, you can compute E(Y) in the usual way.

---

in my case Y would be the number of customers served. It would take on the same values. But I have no idea how I would test if Y=0, Y=1, Y=2 or Y=3?

hope someone can help me understand that part?

Also it says "now that you have Pr(Y=k)" where does he know that from?

and I take it the "E" means expected(Y)?

---

**Question 4:**
What is the expected number of costumors sent away on a given hour?

this question is obviously related to the first one. Hopefully I'll figure it out when I know how to calculate Question 3.

Hope you can help me out :)

Comment: If Y=min(X,3), then "For Pr(Y=3), compute 1−Pr(X≤3)" should read "For Pr(Y=3), compute 1−Pr(X≤2)".

Comment: thanks Did.

I think I understand it now:

The expected number of customers served on a day is now 3 right?

1−Pr(X≤3) = 0.85715
1−Pr(X≤2) = 0.67670
1−Pr(X≤1) = 0.40602

Comment: If the number X of customers arriving is X≥3 then the number Y of customers served is Y=3. Otherwise, X≤2 and Y=X hence Y≤2. Thus, P(Y=3)=P(X≥3)=1−Pr(X≤2).

Comment: so for 
P(Y=3) is that 0.323300 and 
P(Y=2) = 0.59398?
and how do I calculate P(Y=1) then? I use this method: $$1-e^{-2}\left(1+\frac{2}{1!}+\frac{2^2}{2!}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

If the distribution of $X$ is Poisson with parameter $\mu=2$ and if $Y=\min(X,3)$, then:

- $P[Y=0]=P[X=0]=\mathrm e^{-\mu}=1/\mathrm e^2$
- $P[Y=1]=P[X=1]=\mathrm e^{-\mu}\mu=2/\mathrm e^2$
- $P[Y=2]=P[X=2]=\mathrm e^{-\mu}\mu^2/2=2/\mathrm e^2$
- $P[Y=3]=P[X\geqslant3]=1-P[X=0]-P[X=1]-P[X=2]$, that is, $P[Y=3]=1-\mathrm e^{-\mu}(1+\mu+\mu^2/2)=1-5/\mathrm e^2$

Comment: thanks again Did.

Thats what I need for the assignment. I understand the method. But apparently I got the idea of calculating e.g. P[X=1] completly wrong.

Could you help me understand this please? how do I calculate that?

once again thank you soo much for the help!

Comment: in the mean time I tried to figure out question 4.

after some reading I found that. We let Let Z be the number of customers sent away. We want E(Z). The easiest way to calculate this is to note that Y+Z=X (here Y is the random variable we used i Question 5). Thus E(Y+Z)=E(X)=2. By the linearity of expectation, we have E(Y+Z)=E(Y)+E(Z). Thus E(Z)=2−E(Y).

So is that simply 2-.32335 = 1.67665?

Comment: Also how can question 3 and 4 be correct if the mean of customers arrivinng at the restaurant an hour is 2?

the the expected amount of customers arriving should be around 2 as well?

and the expected number of customers sent away should definitely be less than 1?

Comment: Here is a counterexample to the assertion in your last comment (which misses the randomness of the model): assume that each hour either 0 or 2n customers arrive, 0 with probability 1-1/n and 2n with probability 1/n. Then E(X)=2 and E(Z)=2-2/n hence, if n is large, nearly every customer is sent away although the mean number of customers arriving each hour is 2, the exact capacity of the restaurant.